# Saving primary calendar as default

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, caldav

When I authorize to Google Calendar Caldav I want to save the email address as default calendar. But the email address is not returned in the response only things like the access token.

When authorizing you don't fill in the email address on your page but you choose it in the authorization panel of google itself.

So is there a way to still retrieve the users gmail address which he used to login with?

I know that in Google Calendar itself you can use "[primary](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get)" instead. Outlook gives you the option to fill in "me". But I can't find an option like this for [Caldav](https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide).

Comment: Any chance you can make a request to the Google analytics api directly? without using caldav?  If so i have an answer for you.

Comment: The whole project is already made in Caldav it is not an option to convert it to the Google Calendar API